# /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found - error from the application build using pyinstaller

Tags: python, linux, debian, pyinstaller, glibc

I have used `pyinstaller` to build my python scripts to run as stand alone application without any dependencies of python installation or modules installation. But now i am getting /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by) error in different servers with my build application.

I have read suggestions over internet that, i need to update glibc version or i should re-compiled as per server version. But that is not possible in my case, that is why i have built stand alone application with pyinstaller.

Please suggest solution. I need to run this application in 'n' no.of servers, so upgrading glibc is not possible. is there any way to add this library file in build package?

Answer (score 3):

> But that is not possible in my case

Yes, it is.

You must either build the application to match your desired target environment, or you must make your target environment satisfy the requirements of that applicaition you built.

One way to make the application match target environment is to build it in a chroot or a docker container that matches the target.

> that is why i have built stand alone application with pyinstaller.

You are *not* building a "stand alone" application. You are building something that depends on GLIBC-2.14, and trying to run it on a system that doesn't have that (or newer) version of GLIBC.

> I need to run this application in 'n' no.of servers, so upgrading glibc is not possible

Sure it is. You are running your application on ancient GLIBC version (version 2.14 was released in 2011). Since then, many CVEs have been discovered and fixed. By continuing to use ancient version, you are exposing your company to significant risks.